# Update a single option on a HighCharts chart

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to update a single option of a chart after creation. So in my situation I wanna toggle the type of the xAxis from `linear` to `logarithmic`. At the moment I redraw whole chart but this seems to be a bit odd.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657588/highcharts-dynamically-change-chart-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment it is not available (only use of your way), but in a next relase (3.0) should be.